QSWAT+ Parameters SWAT Editor error
When I attempt to go to Step 3 "Edit Inputs and Run SWAT" I encounter the error "Cannot find SWAT Editor C:\SWAT\SWATEditor\SWATEditor.exe. is it installed".
There is no SWATEditor.exe in the C:\SWAT\SWATEditor\ directory. There is a SWATPlus Editor.exe in the C:\SWAT\SWATPlus\SWATPlusEditor\ directory.
If I select C:\SWAT\SWATPlus\SWATPlusEditor\ directory from the QSWAT Parameters box, for the SWAT editor directory, then when I select "Save" I get another error "cannot find the SWAT editor C:/SWAT/SWATPlus/SWATPlusEditor\SWATEditor.exe".
There does not appear to be a way to select the SWATPlus Editor.exe file in the  C:\SWAT\SWATPlus\SWATPlusEditor\ directory. QSWAT is forcing the choice of only using SWATEditor.ex
